# Setting SMTP on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, smtp, iis-express

I wonder if anyone could help me setting up  my SMTP on IIS Express.

Comment: Need much more detail. We can't help unless you can pose a much more detailed question.

Answer (score 8):

from my understanding IISExpress only supports HTTP and HTTPS - it doesn't include FTP or SMTP support

this is full documentation on IIS Express http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/860/iis-express/

Answer (score 4):

IIS Express does not support SMTP.

From the [IIS Express FAQ](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/):

Q: Does IIS Express support non-HTTP protocols such as net.tcp or MSMQ?

A: No. **IIS Express only supports HTTP and HTTPS** as its protocol.

Comment: so how does IISEXPRESS could send emails ? I could send an email to my self.

Answer (score 1):

I have always had an issue with IIS including an SMTP component, it has never made any logical sense to me. But then again I have always had an SMTP server I managed to test against. I have to reccomend Neptune as a nice little SMTP testing tool. http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2009/07/30/Automated-Testing-E_2D00_Mail-with-Neptune.aspx 
A friend of mine wrote it with unit and integration testing in mind. I have found it works great as a developer SMTP tool when you need to include sending e-mails in your application. It is super easy to setup and get running.