# PasswordRecovery on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, password-recovery

I am using the ASP.NET membership provider. And I want to set up Password Recovery as in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178335%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I am using the IIS Express that is default in Visual Studio 2012. But it looks like IIS Express does not support SMTP as it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795978/setting-smtp-on-iis-express).

So what are my options to go about setting up a password recovery?

Comment: In my dev environment I use http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/ Quick, easy and works well!

Comment: thanks @cheesemacfly for suggestion. i ended up just using the gmail. works pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution I found without installing anything, was to use gmail. as it is discussed over here http://forums.asp.net/t/1124257.aspx/1
it works pretty well so far for development purposes.

so from that post.

This is what the mail setting in the web config should look like :

```
<system.net>
     <mailSettings>
       <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="username@gmail.com">
         <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName=username" password="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
       </smtp>
     </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
```

aspx page :

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server" 
        onsendingmail="PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail">
     </asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

code behind (C#):

```
 protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
     {
         MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();


        mm.From = e.Message.From;

        mm.Subject = e.Message.Subject.ToString();

        mm.To.Add(e.Message.To[0]);

        mm.Body = e.Message.Body;
         SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); 
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        smtp.Send(mm);
         e.Cancel = true; 
    }
```